# Regular expression pattern $

Tags: regex

The source text is as following:

```
Time: 8/26/2015 12:12:12 AM
```

I want to extract both of time and date values, so I used this pattern:

```
Time: (.+)
```

But because of that some times the source is like this:

```
Time: 8/26/2015 13:13:13 Fired by event
```

I had to add to the pattern that my text **should ends with AM or PM**, but with the following pattern I don't get my considered result:

```
Time: (.+) AM|PM$
```

Would you please help me to find the correct pattern?

> Note: I don't want the times like `8/26/2015 13:13:13`, I want **only
>   the times that ends with AM or PM**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Time: (\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+)
```

---

**Update**: For times ending with AM/PM only you'll have to add `(AM|PM)` group at the end:

```
Time: (\d+\/\d+\/\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+) (AM|PM)
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jT0nG9/1)

Comment: I did some edits to my question, I don't want the times that does not end with AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
Time:\s+(.+)\s+(AM|PM)$
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
Time:\s(.*?)\s(.*?)\s.*
```

Group 1 is date
Group 2 is time

However, It may be easier to just split the string on whitespace and take the second and third items